# Card view is no display, my recyclerview is working but card view is no visible in the app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm using the android studio to build an application. Since I'm new to android studio development, unable to figure out the problem. My app is running properly. but the card view is not visible in recyclerview. please help me.
this is my recycler adapterview code

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> uploads;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.uploads = uploads;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void setList(List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.tv_book_title.setText(upload.getName());

    Glide.with(mContext).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imd_book_thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploads == null ? 0 : uploads.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_book_title;
    ImageView imd_book_thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_book_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_id);
        imd_book_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_img_id);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_id);
    }
}
```

}

and this is the my card view **XML file code**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/card_view_id"


android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/book_img_id"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#2d2">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
        android:id="@+id/book_title_id"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

my mainactivity is follow

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    uploads = new ArrayList<>();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("upload");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Upload upload= postsnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.add(upload);
            }

            adapter.setList(uploads);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Change card view width to match_parent and height to wrap_content and add notfiydataset changed to setList() method after modify the list

Comment: I did but It's not work

Comment: Add the screenshot of the database to your question.

Comment: Hasan  Boy Taam thank you very much I will solved my problem in real-time database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that in the method for setting the data

```
public void setList(List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
}
```

You are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so the method `getItemCount` won't be called again, and you will have empty RV, so that is why no items are shown.

EDIT:

```
public void setList(List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I think i did it in main activity, I'm upload it to question please check it and give me a solution

Comment: It is still the same. You pass the data inside `onDataChange`. You have to add `notifyDataSetChanged` inside your `setList()` in adapter, after you set data to list.

Comment: in layout inspector I found this E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the cardView with another view. I would suggest you to use ConstraintLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_id"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/book_img_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="#2d2"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Inspect Layout and check where is cardView or what size it has.

Check here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: I try it but I can't find card view on it, only recycler view is in that

Comment: and get this problem E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call **notifyDataSetChanged** when you update your adapter.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ....
    adapter.setList(uploads);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: in layout inspector I found this E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.